# how we got ensured that kernel is loaded at this address 2000h:0000h (segment:offset)

Tags: operating-system

in mikeos operating system i noticed this assembly code in bootloader

jmp 2000h:0000h         ; Jump to entry point of loaded kernel!
but i am not getting when the kernel is loaded at this location. please sombody help.sorry due to poor English .

Comment: first, 2000h:0000h is not sector:offset, but segment:offset. *** very *** different!.

Comment: See my answer for explanation! If it is what you wanted please accept it! :)

Comment: @Levente Kurusa . i am not good in assembly ..that is why i am facing trouble. but kernel is assembled or written on floppy before.. so it should start at exactly same location and then we told it to our bootloader? right? but one more doubt is how we load any code to exact location of floppy drive?

Comment: The kernel resides on the FAT12 formatted floppy drive, the assembly code I had provided in my answer, which is in fact MikeOS's code, ensures that it copies from disk to the RAM.

Comment: Sir i am asking , how we can put any code to exact location of floppy drive like here 2000:0000 . is there any way to skip any segment and start writing to next segment?

Comment: Please look up Memory Segmentation on osdev.org! :) That where I learned all this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MikeOS loads its kernel from the floppy drive. 
Code from MikeOS in load_file_sector label:

```
mov ax, 2000h           ; Set buffer past what we've already read
mov es, ax
mov bx, word [pointer]

pop ax              ; Save in case we (or int calls) lose it
push ax

stc
int 13h
```

the BIOS interrupt 0x13 with AH=02 is the `read_sector`. It reads the sector to the location pointed by `es:bx`. MikeOS sets this to 2000h:2000h. That is where it loads the kernel!